# VSIX - Embed WpfTextView in custom window

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Does anybody know if it is possible tot embed the built in text viewer of Visual Studio into a custom WPF window? The text view should contain a custom text, that's not necessary linked with another textbuffer or file. We would like to have syntax coloring and intellisense for C# and XML languages.

Comment: Probably. This is done for completion support in the watch window, for example. It will most definitely be linked to an `ITextBuffer`, though.

Comment: I'd start looking at the `ITextEditorFactoryService.CreateTextViewHost` method in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.UI.Wpf assembly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937232/syntax-highlight-doesnt-work-for-ivsinvisibleeditor and https://joshvarty.com/2014/08/01/ripping-the-visual-studio-editor-apart-with-projection-buffers/ and https://github.com/SLaks/VSEmbed

Comment: Do you mean outside of Visual Studio? VsEmbed from SLaks is AFAIK the only example available (and a crazy piece of code... good luck! plus when you run it, it's almost as slow as running Visual Studio...). There used to be what was called Visual Studio Shell (it's a VS shell with your program in it, for example, SQL Management Studio is such a beast), but it's not available for Visual Studio 2017. https://vspartner.com/pages/vsshells

Comment: No I meant in a Visual Studio extension, not in a separate application.