# Syntax highlighting doesn't work for C# invisible editor in custom pane

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I want to host two different VS C#/VB editors (as wpf controls) created via the IVsInvisibleEditorManager.RegisterInvisibleEditor method in my custom pane inherited from IVsUIElementPane and IVsPersistDocData interfaces. But highlighting works only for one editor.
I use the following code for creating editor

```
private void SetLeftDisplayedFile(string filePath)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();


    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(_invisibleEditorManager.RegisterInvisibleEditor(filePath,
                                                                               pProject: null,
                                                                               dwFlags: (uint)_EDITORREGFLAGS.RIEF_ENABLECACHING,
                                                                               pFactory: null,
                                                                               ppEditor: out invisibleEditorLeft));

    RegisterDocument(filePath);

    IntPtr docDataPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
    Guid guidIVSTextLines = typeof(IVsTextLines).GUID;
    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(invisibleEditorLeft.GetDocData(fEnsureWritable: 1, riid: ref guidIVSTextLines, ppDocData: out docDataPointer));
    try
    {
        IVsTextLines docData = (IVsTextLines)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(docDataPointer);
        //Create a code window adapter.
        codeWindowLeft = _editorAdapter.CreateVsCodeWindowAdapter(VisualStudioServices.OLEServiceProvider);
        const _codewindowbehaviorflags CWB_DISABLEDIFF = (_codewindowbehaviorflags)0x04;

        IVsCodeWindowEx codeWindowEx = (IVsCodeWindowEx)codeWindowLeft;
        INITVIEW[] initView = new INITVIEW[1];
        codeWindowEx.Initialize((uint)_codewindowbehaviorflags.CWB_DISABLESPLITTER | (uint)CWB_DISABLEDIFF,
                                 VSUSERCONTEXTATTRIBUTEUSAGE.VSUC_Usage_Filter,
                                 szNameAuxUserContext: "",
                                 szValueAuxUserContext: "",
                                 InitViewFlags: 0,
                                 pInitView: initView);

        //Associate our IVsTextLines with our new code window.
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(codeWindowLeft.SetBuffer((IVsTextLines)docData));

        //Get our text view for our editor which we will use to get the WPF control that hosts said editor.
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(codeWindowLeft.GetPrimaryView(out textViewLeft));

        //Get our WPF host from our text view (from our code window).
        IWpfTextViewHost textViewHost = _editorAdapter.GetWpfTextViewHost(textViewLeft);

        Debug.Assert(this.control != null);

        //We already have an open window, so just insert this editor in place of the old one.
        this.control.InsertLeftEditor(textViewHost.HostControl);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (docDataPointer != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            //Release the doc data from the invisible editor since it gave us a ref-counted copy.
            Marshal.Release(docDataPointer);
        }
    }
}
private uint RegisterDocument(string targetFile)
{
    //Then when creating the IVsInvisibleEditor, find and lock the document
    uint itemID;
    IntPtr docData;
    uint docCookie;
    IVsHierarchy hierarchy;
    var runningDocTable = (IVsRunningDocumentTable)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsRunningDocumentTable));

    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(runningDocTable.FindAndLockDocument(
        dwRDTLockType: (uint)_VSRDTFLAGS.RDT_NoLock,
        pszMkDocument: targetFile,
        ppHier: out hierarchy,
        pitemid: out itemID,
        ppunkDocData: out docData,
        pdwCookie: out docCookie));

    return docCookie;
}
```

The custom pane (see all code in my project on [One Drive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuZUJhfybjtRgc0q4VnlkU3E_o3p6g?e=ytPT4M)):

```
VsWpfCompareWindowPane : IVsUIElementPane, IVsPersistDocData
{
    ...
    int IVsUIElementPane.CreateUIElementPane(out object punkUIElement)
    {
        if (control == null)
        {
            control = new WpfCompareControl();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_leftFilePath))
            {
                SetLeftDisplayedFile(_leftFilePath);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_rightFilePath))
            {
                SetRightDisplayedFile(_rightFilePath);
            }
        }
        punkUIElement = control;
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }
    ...
}
```

In the WpfCompareControl I use two ContentControl.

STR:

1. List item
2. Download and build my solution on [One Drive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuZUJhfybjtRgc0q4VnlkU3E_o3p6g?e=ytPT4M)
3. In the properties of the "TestEditor" project, select Start External program and use the path to VS 2019 devenv.exe
4. Set the command line arguments to “/rootsuffix Exp”
5. Save and then run the solution or [download](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuZUJhfybjtRgc0nF0etnW9-EfIk8Q?e=c1NmAj) and install the .vsix
6. Create test.testdiff file and add paths to two .cs files on your computer. For example

```
C:\Users\MstislavS\Source\repos\WpfApp10\WpfApp10\MainWindow2.xaml.cs
C:\Users\MstislavS\Source\repos\WpfApp10\WpfApp10\MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

7. Save the test.testdiff file
8. In VS, click File-Open-File... and select the test.testdiff file.

Actual Result: Syntax highlighting and intellisence works only in the right editor, the left editor does not have syntax
[highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XCJv.png)
but includes the same parts as the right one (bar items, scroll, zoom)

Expected result: Syntax highlighting works in both editors.

Note: Syntax highlighting will work in both editors if you open any .cs file (File-Open-file...) after starting VS before opening the test.testdiff file.
I have found the following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937232/syntax-highlight-doesnt-work-for-ivsinvisibleeditor). Calling the runningDocTable.FindAndLockDocument and SetLanguageServiceID methods does not solve the problem.
This [post](https://developercommunityapi.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/content/problem/498617/projectionbuffertutorial-gives-error-in-dev16.html) describes new mechanisms of creating editors in VS 2019, but doesn't solve my problem.

This problem reproduces only for Roslyn languages **C#** and **VB**, but xml, typescript, json etc editors work fine!
Syntax highlighting also does not work in [ProjectionBufferTutorial](https://github.com/JoshVarty/ProjectionBufferTutorial) example.